# Clarification required on gaps in rational numbers from Walter Rudins book

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

In the following question posted

[Few Questions about analysis in Rudins book](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/895647/967449)

I did not understood how they associated the rational number q with the equation.
$$ q = p - \frac{p^2 - 2}{p + 2} $$

Need to understand on how $$ p^2 - 2 $$ and $$ p + 2 $$ is chosen.